# Azure DevOps - Custom Build Task Visibility

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm learning Azure DevOps. I'm interested in creating a [custom build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts). My question is, is it possible to create a private, custom build task? In other words, I only want my build task to be visible within my organization.

Is it possible to set custom build task visibility to certain scopes (i.e. project, groups, organization, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manage tasks within an account with the [`tfx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tfx-cli) command line tool, including uploading your own. You don't need to publish an extension to the marketplace.

Beyond that, no. Tasks exist within an account, and you cannot control their visibility within an account.

Comment: You can only change the visibility of tasks to be shown in build or release- (or both) editors.

Comment: @D.J. Last I saw, you couldn't even do that. Although there's a visibility option in the `task.json`, it didn't actually do anything. That may have changed at some point, of course.

Comment: wow... now that i checked this i see that they have actually changed that. i now see tasks in release-editor that are not supposed to be seen there. thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a custom private task. Take a look at the "Publish Extension" task, you can set the extension visibility to private.

In terms of visibility, you will not be able to scope to a project, etc. To handle that I created a separate account that I use as my dev environment. My release pipeline pushes to the dev env, and upon approval releases to "prod" which is the account the rest of our department uses.